# Need help understanding relationships for model in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, laravel-8

To keep my development skills somewhat up to date, I started working on a side project in Laravel to help keep track of gifts given and received during this Christmas holiday. I thought it would be nice to keep track of which gifts I have given others, and what gifts I receieved from family and friends. Also to keep track of gifts to my 2 year old.

As you need to register in the app, it has the default `User` model. An user can add gifts that they will give to a `Person`, for example your dad. Then you would register your dad as `Person` and then create a `Gift` and relate these two.

However, the trouble emerges when a `Gift` either can be *received* or *given*, meaning it has two states. I don't think that would be too much trouble to figure out. But the gift can also have multiple receivers (say a joint gift to both your mom and dad), and it can have multiple givers, and the gift is from you and your sibling to your mom and dad. The thing I cannot quite understand is the part where a `Gift` has a many to many relationship with both `User`, `Person` and/or a combination.

How would that be solved? I guess there would be some way of polymorphic relationship, although I haven't grasped the concept 100% yet.

Comment: I would argue that your assumption about many to many between gift-user (givers) and gift-person (receivers) is perfectly fine. I do not think polymorphic is the way to go.

Comment: @user3532758 What I don't understand is, say that i have a `receivers` relation on the `Gift` model. This has to relate to say one `User` and one `Person`. Hence the polymorphic relation?

Comment: It's not that you cannot use polymorphic to achieve this, but, this maybe subjective, many to many between the tables would be better imo and more performant (easily observed only if db is significantly large) than the polymorphic approach. For polymorphic, you would have a `giftable` table where `giftable_type` would either be `User` or `Person` model.

Comment: @user3532758 Well, the only thing I'm wondering about then is how to solve the many to many relationship between gift-user gift-person could be of `User` or `Person` class. I should also be able to add a gift I received from someone else that will be added as `Person`. Then `gift.receiver` would point to my `User` instance, but `gift.giver` will point to a `Person`. But it could also be the other way around.

Comment: Then, to manage gifts, how about using the person model only? You can use the User model to manage authentication, user will also have a person instance. Person model can have a many to many relationship with gitfts, and in the gift_person pivot table columns `giver_id`, `receiver_id` would point to the id on persons table. I can post this idea in detail as an answer if you want.